# Call web service from stored procedure - special characters aren't shown correctly

Tags: sql, web-services, sql-server-2012, character

I'm trying to call a web service from a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012:

```
    DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(8000)
    DECLARE @Object AS INT;
    DECLARE @idoc INT;

    Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @Webservice, 'false'
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
    Exec sp_OADestroy @Object

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @ResponseText
```

The call works but the result string `@ResponseText` won't convert some special characters. An `ë` (with umlaut) turns into `?` and the next character is cut of. The `ë` is also shown as `ë` in the source of the xml, so it isn't translated to `&euml;`

The `<` and `&`characters as are translated well (into `&lt;` and `&amp;`) and these give no problems.

The returning XML is from the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` format and it displays correctly when I open the service in a browser.

Can I do anything to make the `ë` work as well or do I need to change my returning xml and change the `ë` to `&euml;`?

Answer (score 0):

Use NVARCHAR type to resolve this issue.

> An ë (with umlaut) turns into ?

You might need a user function like [this](http://blog.namwarrizvi.com/?p=243)  to encode the resulting string to HTML  for this one

> the next character is cut of, < turns into <, & into &... and
>   so on

Comment: I've changed my message a bit. At first I thougt all special characters gave problems but now it turns out only the characters which arent in the source like '&xxx;' aren't shown correctly.

Comment: I've tried using NVARCHAR but this won't work. VARCHAR is the only type to which I can put my responseText

Comment: In short, if the 'ë' was written like '&euml ;' (without the space ofcourse), it will work. But know it seems the sp_OAMethod doesn't recognize the character 'ë' and changes it with a question mark.

Comment: I don't see why you can't use NVARCHAR. Any errors?

Comment: Yes,
XML parsing: line 1, character 43, unable to switch the encoding

Comment: The sp_xml_preparedocument call can't work with a NVARCHAR it seems. For the rest, I get almost the same results in the NVARCHAR string execpt the 'ë' had disappeared entirely. Not even a question mark.

Comment: It seems the sp_xml_preparedocument function can't handle a NVARCHAR